# Easiest way to generate audit and archive information into a sql database shared by multiple applications

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, architecture, archive, audit

We have several applications that are updating a certain ms sql 2005 table (asp.net web app, c# windows service, email parser to database automation tool (uses sql + VB)) and would like to store audit information on the table. E.g. ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate where ModifiedBy = Name of Application updating the record.

We would also like to archive the information on the table; when we update a particular record, store the current record in an myTable_Archive table and stamp it with a date and update the current record in myTable accordingly.

What's the best maintainable and testable approach to solving this while keeping the impact minimal to the existing applications? Or can someone suggest a better route? Calling a store procedure, c# shared library (using nhibernate/ado.net,etc.), or an ms sql 2005 built-in feature if any for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most maintainable (and fairly standard) way of doing this kind of auditing is to use [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx) on the tables in question.

Since they exist entirely in the database, your applications will not change at all.

Of course, triggers will impact performance (since one now changes more than one table in a call).

Comment: Thanks, that's a small change suggestion that would most likely solve my scenario.  Is there a way in the trigger to determine the calling application or process so I can make use of that in the ModifiedBy (application name) field?

Comment: @Luke Hutton - So long as your connection string contains this information, you should be able to retrieve it from system tables. See the answer from @Conrad Frix

Comment: thanks, will go down this route, will create some tests around the triggers.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the easiest is via triggers. To get the ModifiedBy = Name of Application  requirement you'll need to do two things

1) Update the Connections strings to set the Application Name 
e.g. `..Database=Foo;Application Name = Parser;`

2) Then in your trigger you can get the name via

`select program_name from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_id = @@SPID`